# Syntax Error on Increment even though it should be correct

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

This may be due to some stupid error that I simply can't identify, but Python returns a syntax error when I run the following code

```
# Imports
import pygame
import os

# Startup
pygame.init()

# Screen
size = (500, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, pygame.NOFRAME)
pygame.display.set_caption = ("Swinger")
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
# -- Assign Functions --
# -- Assign Classes --
# -- Assign Variables --
#Sets the color of pure white to a variable to be called
WHITE    = (255, 255, 255)
#Sets the player to an image loaded from os path Swinger
Player = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Swinger", "player.png"))
Pointer = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Swinger", "pointer.png"))
#Sets a variable to know whether the scrpt has run once or not
FirstRun = 0
#Sets the variables to allow you to control movement
#Y axis movement Speed
MoveYSpeed = 0
#X axis movement speed
MoveXSpeed = 0
#Assigns the values later used to call the drawing
#of the player
PlayerPos = [255 += MoveXSpeed, 255 += MoveYSpeed]
#Assigns The first value of PlayerPos as a X axis value
PlayerPosX = PlayerPos[0]
#Assigns the second value of PlayerPos as a y axis value
PlayerPosY = PlayerPos[1]
```

it gives me a syntax error on line 31 on the first increment statement, saying that the Equal symbol is wrong:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 31
    PlayerPos = [255 += MoveXSpeed, 255 += MoveYSpeed]
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am just really getting started into coding, so much of the code may not be up to the proper format and I didn't copy all of the code because I thought it may not be relevant considering I get the error before reaching any of the other code.

Comment: `PlayerPos = [255 += MoveXSpeed, 255 += MoveYSpeed]` is not valid Python syntax, no. What did you want to do with that expression?

Comment: I want to be able to increment those values by a seperate variable. Im using pygame and im using those 2 values as the X and Y, so i want to increment them by the movement speed variable when the player holds a certain key.

Comment: And... it actually is. You cannot assign a value to an integer. It already represents one

Comment: @LPK: you can't use statements inside expressions either. `+=` is augmented assignment, a statement.

Comment: yea. another point

Comment: @KarkerCarnesir: but you never even created the `PlayerPos` variable before. Did you mean to just use `+` perhaps? `PlayerPos = [255 + MoveXSpeed, 255 + MoveYSpeed]` will create a list with those two sums as the initial values.

Comment: No, i believe i understand what was wrong with the statement and have managed to fix it, thanks. is there some way to pick a comment as an answer or...

Comment: @KarkerCarnesir: I've posted my suggestions as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PlayerPos = [255 += MoveXSpeed, 255 += MoveYSpeed]` is not valid Python syntax, no. What did you want to do with that expression? `+=` is not an operator, it is a *statement* (like `=` assignment, or `return` or `if test: <block>`), and you can't put statements inside other statements.

Did you mean to just use the `+` addition operator perhaps?

```
PlayerPos = [255 + MoveXSpeed, 255 + MoveYSpeed]
```

will create a list with those two sums as the initial values.

Comment: Would be great if you could explain why the error happened. You are more questioning him than describing the problem

Comment: @LPK: well, there is no description of an expected outcome in the question, so this involves a lot of guessing.

Comment: this answer is premature, because there is no overall logic to the question or the code in the question. none of this would be generally helpful to anyone, and the questioner has said this isn't really what he intended. if the goal here is to have a question and answer that address someone trying to do something like x = y += 255, then all the excess talk here should be trimmed out. but that is such a gross typographical error, i think the whole thing should just be closed.

Comment: @dbliss: agreed, post closed.